# Scope Issue. Accessing object outside of if statement

Tags: r

I'm new to R. My code is below. I have a simple scope question.

I thought that any local variable created such as in my if statement has only a scope within that statement? Still I can access Buy.Signal outside of the if statement. How is this?

My Code

```
library(Quandl)
library(TTR)
library(mail)

RunProgram  <- function () {

  Buy.Signal  <- EMAFind() 

}
EMAFind  <-  function() {

  Quandl.auth("TOKEN")

  mydata  <- Quandl("BCHARTS/BITSTAMPUSD")
  mydata <- mydata[1:30, ]
  mydata <- mydata[order(mydata$Date), ]

  EMA.Short  <- EMA(x = mydata$Close, 11) 
  EMA.Long  <-  EMA(x = mydata$Close, 21)

  if (tail(EMA.Short, 1) > tail(EMA.Long, 1)) {

    Buy.Signal = TRUE

    } else {

    Buy.Signal = FALSE

  }

print (Buy.Signal) #<- WORKS!

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is one of the main differences between C (and C++) and R regarding variable scope. In R the `if` statement followed by `{` bracket does not limit the scope of variables declared within that.

```
 if(x==1)
     { y<-2}       # assigned in .GlobalEnv
 else (x==2)
     {y <-3}       # assigned in .GlobalEnv

 y

 >2     # or 3 of course

 fun <- function(x) {
        varfun <- 3    # assigned in the function environment
        }

 varfun      #we are back in the .GlobalEnv

 >Error: object varfun not found
```

Here is a good link for environments in R http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Why is this? In any other situation (such as when declaring a function) the scoping appplies, but not on if statements? Are there any more situations in R like this?

Comment: Yes, the scope (for a variable initialised with the `<-` operator) is the environment where it has been declared and the environment is the same for all `if` or `for` statements if they belong to the same function. I will edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @uncool Techically speaking, R uses lexical/static scoping instead of dynamic scoping. You can find a video here that might give you some more insight on R workspaces, environments, scoping and function definitions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCu1Xw4h_n8